# Run tests with xcodebuild without signing

Tags: macos, xctest, codesign

##### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to run several tests written in the `XCTest` framework without code signing, for the purpose of not having to deal with the hassle of importing code signing identities on CI.

##### What I've tried

I've removed the development team and set the signing certificate to "Sign to run locally" for both the app and test target. Building with

```bash
xcodebuild build-for-testing -scheme <my scheme>
```

works on both CI and locally, but attempting to run the tests with

```bash
xcodebuild test-without-building -scheme <my scheme>
```

fails after around 10s with the error `<name> (83559) encountered an error (Failed to load the test bundle.`. `<test binary> not valid for use in process: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?` a few lines down sheds more light about the issue. Seems like macOS didn't like the unsigned test bundle and refused to load it.

Running the test command like so:

```bash
 xcodebuild test-without-building -xctestrun /Users/vinkwok/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChessFrontend-carjpisbuprsabeulpsycoxjqjea/Build/Products/ChessFrontend_macosx13.0-arm64.xctestrun -destination "platform=macOS,id=<id>,arch=arm64"
```

throws the following error:

```
Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted. (Underlying Error: The test runner exited with code 1 before checking in. ...)
```

It looks like the same test bundle error is occurring, except this time it's not printed out because the test runner simply failed to start.

I've also attempted to sign the test bundle with my development cert with `codesign`, but that just caused `xcodebuild test-without-building` to complain that the bundle was missing a development team.

Could anyone point me in the right direction about how to run tests on CI environments without the hassle of dealing with signing and code signing identities? Answers would be greatly appreciated!